# Protractor - does anybody know how to click on element with RIGHT MOUSE BUTTON?

Tags: mouse, right-click, protractor

I know that protractor click on element by default with left mouse button. How to do it to click with RIGHT MOUSE BUTTON ?

`el.click('RIGHT');` ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would have done like this:

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(el.find()).perform();
browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();
```

Based on what I saw in [actionsequence.js](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/actionsequence.js) and [Protractor rightClick issue #280](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/280)

Comment: The browser.actions() way seems to have broke in protractor 2.0?

Comment: @KlasMellbourn If there is a breaking change, it should come from Webdriver which has been upgraded in Protractor 2.0. Have you seen its changelog? I'll take a look too. You can also open an issue on Protractor GitHub ;)

Comment: @glepretre I have now raised this issue https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2043

Comment: I got `el.find is not a function`. Had to use `el.getLocation()` instead, but otherwise this worked.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution for this question isn't the best way to go about this. Browser actions' `.click()` method accepts an optional arg for clicking the right button. A better solution, from the [webdriverJs api](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_ActionSequence.html) is:

```
browser.actions()
    .click($('.myElm'), protractor.Button.RIGHT)
    .perform();
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

el.sendKeys(protractor.Key.RIGHT)

Here is the list of keys:
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/key.js

If it doesn't work do this:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/fF_Hcp40KO0

Let me know if it works

Comment: I think that `protractor.Key.RIGHT` performs a right arrow keypress, am I wrong?

Comment: In Protractor 5.4.2 version with Jasmine , below code is no longer working . Could you please suggest something else since it does nothing ? Thank you . browser.actions().mouseMove(el.getLocation()).perform();
  browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();