# How to Right click on specific element, with protractor?

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

How to simulate mouse Right click on given element?

This I already tried and the context menu does not open:

```
var testElem = $('#someElementId span');
return browser.actions().mouseMove(testElem).perform().then(function() {
        return browser.actions().click(testElem, protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();                        
        });
```

This works (highlighting the correct element):

```
var testElem = $('#someElementId span');
return browser.actions().mouseMove(testElem).perform().then(function() {
        return browser.actions().doubleClick(testElem, protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();                      
        });
```

There are no error messages...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protractor - does anybody know how to click on element with RIGHT MOUSE BUTTON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386637/protractor-does-anybody-know-how-to-click-on-element-with-right-mouse-button)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code snippet.

```
var testElem = $('#someElementId span');
var EC = browser.ExpectedConditions;

browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(testElem),10000);

browser.actions().doubleClick(testElem).perform();
```

Comment: Thanks for you replay, Zohair.   The problem is that doubleClick works.  right click does not work...

Comment: firstly move to the element using actions then use below given code line for right click. Might be your problem resolves.  browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();

Comment: Seems like webdriver/protractor issue.   running exactly same code on different machine worked perfectly.    Thanks for you answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(el.find()).perform();
browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();
```

Hope it helps you